# .rubyconfig doesn't open from terminal

Tags: command-line

i installed ruby on ubuntu14.01LTS.how to open .rubyconfig file from terminal using gedit?
it asked denied permission..how to open .rubyconfig file using terminal?

Answer (score 0):

2 potential resolutions here -

- use `sudo`
- change the permissions of .rubyconfig to the current user. eg.
  `sudo chown <username>:<group> .rubyconfig`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Martin's answer, you can do:

- `sudo nano .rubyconfig` (replace nano with another editor if you're more comfortable (e.g. `pico` `vim` `emacs`)
- `gksudo gedit .rubyconfig` will open the ruby config in a gui program for you, again replacing `gedit` with another editor of your choice (`pluma`, `geany`, etc)
- You can use `chown` to change the ownership of the file with `sudo chown <username> .rubyconfig`. Be careful doing this though, as it will make it that other users cannot change it. Depending on where it is, this may be undesirable.

Where is the .rubyconfig kept? If possible, try to make it be in your home directory so that you do have the ability to edit it easily, potentially by putting a soft link with `ln -s` to a location in your home directory (e.g. `~/.rubyconfig`)